# Can't install dependencies in docker container

Tags: python, docker, python-poetry

I'm using `poetry` library to manage project dependencies, so when I use

`docker build --tag=helloworld .`

I got  this error

```
[AttributeError]               
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

Installing breaks on `umongo (2.1.0)` package

Here is my `pyproject.toml` file

```
[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "^3.7.0"
asyncio = "^3.4"
aiohttp = "^3.4"
motor = "^2.0"
umongo = "^2.0"
pyyaml = "^3.13"

[tool.poetry.dev-dependencies]
pytest = "^3.4"
black = {version = "^18.3-alpha.0",allows-prereleases = true}
mypy = "^0.650.0"
wemake-python-styleguide = "^0.5.1"
pytest-mock = "^1.10"
pytest-asyncio = "^0.9.0"
pytest-aiohttp = "^0.3.0"
```

And `poetry.lock`
https://pastebin.com/kUjAKJHM

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.7.1-alpine

RUN mkdir -p /opt/project/todo_api
RUN pip --no-cache-dir install poetry

COPY ./pyproject.toml /opt/project
COPY poetry.lock /opt/project

RUN cd /opt/project && poetry install --no-dev

COPY ./todo_api /opt/project/todo_api
COPY ./todo_api.yml /opt/project/todo_api.yml

WORKDIR /opt/project

ENTRYPOINT poetry run python -m aiohttp.web todo_api.main:main
```

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with poetry but, on first blush (and a Google search), the error appears to be regex related and possibly an error in poetry itself. Have you tried specifying `umongo` at version `2.1.0` (https://pypi.org/project/umongo/)?

Comment: @DazWilkin I've tried, but issue still persisted

Comment: Interesting. For completeness, please include your `Dockerfile`

Comment: @DazWilkin done

Comment: Three things to try: (A) Python 3.7.4 instead of 3.7.1. (B) Can you install via Poetry outside of Docker? (C) If yes, does it work with non-Alpine Docker image, e.g. `python:3.7.4-slim-buster`?

Comment: @ItamarTurner-Trauring a) Tried, no success. b) Yes. c) No success

Comment: I repro'd the issue. I did not include the lock file (as I think this should be regenerated by the build?). I had to add a `[tool.poetry]` section (with `name=`,`version=`, and `authors=[...]`) then it works for me.

Comment: Feedback: if you move `WORKDIR /opt/project` below `FROM`, this effectively does `mkdir -p /opt/project && cc /opt/project`, so you can remove those commands and you can revise references to your container directory to `./` instead of `/opt/project` in the other commands.

Comment: Lock file should _not_ be regenerated by the build. That's the whole point of the lockfile! see e.g. here: https://pythonspeed.com/articles/pipenv-docker/

Comment: @Skufler perhaps the docker image ends up using different version of poetry than you have on your main machine? Try `pip install poetry==<version on host>` in your Dockerfile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following works for me:

```
FROM python:3.7.1-alpine

WORKDIR /opt/project

RUN pip install --upgrade pip && pip --no-cache-dir install poetry

COPY ./pyproject.toml .

RUN poetry install --no-dev
```

with pyproject.toml:

```
[tool.poetry]
name = "57331667"
version = "0.0.1"
authors = ["skufler <skufler@email.com>"]

[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "^3.7.0"
asyncio = "^3.4"
aiohttp = "^3.4"
motor = "^2.0"
umongo = "^2.0"
pyyaml = "^3.13"

[tool.poetry.dev-dependencies]
pytest = "^3.4"
black = {version = "^18.3-alpha.0",allows-prereleases = true}
mypy = "^0.650.0"
wemake-python-styleguide = "^0.5.1"
pytest-mock = "^1.10"
pytest-asyncio = "^0.9.0"
pytest-aiohttp = "^0.3.0"
```

Then:

```sh
docker build --tag=57331667 --file=./Dockerfile .
```

results:

```sh
...
Creating virtualenv 57331667-py3.7 in /root/.cache/pypoetry/virtualenvs
Updating dependencies
Resolving dependencies...

Writing lock file


Package operations: 15 installs, 0 updates, 0 removals

  - Installing idna (2.8)
  - Installing multidict (4.5.2)
  - Installing six (1.12.0)
  - Installing async-timeout (3.0.1)
  - Installing attrs (18.2.0)
  - Installing chardet (3.0.4)
  - Installing marshmallow (2.19.5)
  - Installing pymongo (3.8.0)
  - Installing python-dateutil (2.8.0)
  - Installing yarl (1.3.0)
  - Installing aiohttp (3.5.4)
  - Installing asyncio (3.4.3)
  - Installing motor (2.0.0)
  - Installing pyyaml (3.13)
  - Installing umongo (2.1.0)
Removing intermediate container c6a9c7652b5c
 ---> 89354562cf16
Successfully built 89354562cf16
Successfully tagged 57331667:latest
```

Comment: I recommend you start from this working configuration and step through transforming it into the configuration that doesn't work until you find what's broken. There may be more than one issue.

Answer (score 6):

### Alternative approach

Don't install `poetry` into your deployment environment. It's a package management tool, which aims to improve development of and collaboration on libraries. If you want to deploy an application, you only need a package installer (read: `pip`) - and the opinionated stance of `poetry` regarding the build process and virtual environments is harmful rather than helpful there.

In this case, the artifacts you want to copy into your docker image are **1)** your most recent build of the library you work on and **2)** a wheelhouse of tested dependencies, as defined by `poetry.lock`.

The first one is easy, run `poetry build -f wheel` and you have a nicely portable wheel. The second one is not yet easy, because `poetry` doesn't support building wheelhouses (and maybe never will), and `pip wheel` does not accept `poetry.lock`'s file format. So if you want go down this road, you need to work on a beta build of `poetry` (`v1.0.0b7` is rather stable) that supports `poetry export -f requirements.txt > requirements.txt`, which lets you create a `requirements.txt` file equivalent to your current lockfile.

Once you got that, you can run `pip wheel -w dist -r requirements.txt`, and *finally*, you're done creating all the artifacts for the docker image. Now, the following will work:

```
FROM python:3.7.1-alpine

WORKDIR /opt/project

COPY dist dist

RUN pip install --no-index --find-links dist todo_api

ENTRYPOINT python -m aiohttp.web todo_api.main:main
```

### Pros

- no unnecessary dependency on `poetry` in your server (might be relevant, since it's still `<v1.0`)
- you skip the virtualenv in your server and install everything right into the system (you might still choose to create a virtualenv on your own and install your app into that, since [installing your application into the system python's side-packages can lead to problems](https://hynek.me/articles/virtualenv-lives/))
- your installation step doesn't run against pypi, so this deployment is guaranteed to work as far as you tested it (this is a very important point in many business settings)

### Cons

- it's a bit of a pain if you do it by hand each time, the target executor here should be a CI/CD and not a human
- if the architecture of your workstation and the docker image differ, the wheels you build and copy over might not be compatible

Answer (score 0):

If you want to install it with pip3 in production, here's how the latest version of Poetry (late 2021) can export a requirements.txt file:

```sh
# Production with no development dependencies
poetry export --no-interaction --no-ansi --without-hashes --format requirements.txt --output ./requirements.prod.txt

# For development, including development dependencies
poetry export --no-interaction --no-ansi --without-hashes --format requirements.txt --dev --output ./requirements.dev.txt
```